# scp permission denied after 'hardening' with bastille

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, scp

I recently 'hardened' two Ubuntu servers using [Bastille](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BastilleLinux), and now I get *permission denied: scp* whenever I try to scp files in.

- SSH login works fine.
- I've tried adding an */scp-dump* folder with 777 permissions and still get the same error, so I don't believe it is a permission issue.
- Tailing */var/log/auth.log* doesn't really give any information, apart from

  ```
  Oct  1 23:08:39 localhost sshd[20876]: Accepted publickey for some-user from [redacted ip] port 49250 ssh2
  Oct  1 23:08:40 localhost sshd[20884]: Received disconnect from [redacted ip]: 11: disconnected by user
  ```
- Using the *-v* flag with scp outputs the following:

  ```
  Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host some-domain.com, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t -- /scpdump
  OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
  debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/some-user/.ssh/config
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to some-domain.com [12.34.56.78] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /Users/some-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
  debug1: identity file /Users/some-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/some-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/some-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
  debug1: Server host key: RSA 8e:83:21:4a:9c:be:57:56:b1:07:5a:14:68:8a:47:dc
  debug1: Host 'some-domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /Users/some-user/.ssh/known_hosts:17
  debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/some-user/.ssh/id_rsa
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
  debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
  debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
  Authenticated to some-domain.com ([12.34.56.78]:22).
  debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
  debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
  debug1: Entering interactive session.
  debug1: Sending environment.
  debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
  debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = C
  debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_AU.utf-8
  debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_AU.utf-8
  debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_AU.utf-8
  debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_AU.utf-8
  debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = en_AU.utf-8
  debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- /scpdump
  zsh:1: permission denied: scp
  debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
  debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
  debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
  debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
  Transferred: sent 2880, received 2504 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
  Bytes per second: sent 4563.7, received 3967.9
  debug1: Exit status 126
  lost connection
  ```

Any idea where the permission denied might be coming from, config files I can look into, or other logs I should be looking at?

Comment: Bastille has an [undo/revert](http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/undoing_bastille.htm) option. You may be able to find your original ssh files and compare the configurations that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh:1: permission denied: scp` looks like it is not allowed to run `scp` on the remote side; check the permissions there. Have you tried running `scp` on that machine to pull the files from elsewhere (vs. push)?

Comment: Spot on, thank you! It looks like Bastille makes */usr/bin/ssh* and */usr/bin/scp* non-executable - *chmod a+x* on both did the trick.